LTspice behavioral model: Use a computed variable name as time input
Trying to run a LTspice simulation with a parameter computed (time250) as an input to timedelay on apulse voltage source. Any help with syntax or ckt correction advice

get this error always

Voltage source param:

You need to fill in Ton and Tperiod. But is this what you’re asking?

just edited the image, wanted to include a computed time as an input for delay parameter in voltage source (Pulse here)

I haven't tested it myself, but I'm inclined to think that it won't work. There are some parameters that need to be determined at the beginning of the simulation and can't be computed by things that occur later in the simulation, this looks like it may be one of those.

You need a .param statement for time250. .meas statements only measure a value and can't be used for parameters. Something like this:
.param time250=12ms

The time parameters for a voltage source need to be constants, the simulation won't be able to start until this is defined. If you need to iteratively find it, try a param step command. You can then plug this value back into the simulation.
